# What does 'subha-n-allah' mean?

Tags: arabic

What does 'subha-n-allah' mean? I've often heard this being used within the Bangladeshi community, but it just occured to me that I don't know what it means. Where does it come from, and how is it written in arabic.

Answer (score 4):

Subhan'Allāh (Arabic سبحان الله) is an Arabic phrase often translated as "Glorious is Allah." You use it to express both your astonishment and gratitude in a situation where you think that the happening, or bounty, or unique situation can arise only out of the Glory of Allah Subhanatawala.

It is also a great and rewarding act to read this whenever you get an opportunity or after fard prayer (33 times).

Please take a look at [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subhan'Allah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subhan%27Allah) for further details. Or see http://islam.about.com/od/glossary/g/subhanallah.htm  for a shorter version.

*(Happy to answer you question, but you could get the answer by a simple Google search.)*